# Free dates in reservation system

Tags: django

I am working on a reservation system, and I can not find a good way to select free dates. Here is my model:

```
class rental_group(models.Model):
    group_title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    description = models.TextField()

class rental_units(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(rental_group)
    number = models.CharField(max_length = 6)

class Reservations(models.Model):
    #name = models.ForeignKey(customer)
    rental_unit = models.ForeignKey(rental_units)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

I tried to select available rooms with this query:

```
rental_units.objects.filter(group__rental_group = 'Bungalow').exclude(Q(Reservations__start_date__lt = arrival)&Q(Reservations__end_date__gt = arrival)|Q(Reservations__start_date__lt = departure)&Q(Reservations__end_date__gt = departure))
```

This works perfect when there is only one reservation. When there are more reservations on the same number, things go wrong. For example when I have two reservations on number 120 this query returns 120 twice when everything is available. And 120 is returns once if the the new reservation is between one of the old reservetaion dates (should be zero "not availble")

Is this possible with a query? Or should I iter over the reservations, and remove the reservated house from a list (which could take a lot of time when there are lots of reservations)

Answer (score 1):

You want Reservations, not rental_units, so filter them:

```
Reservations.objects\
.filter(rental_unit__group__group_title='Bungalow')\
.exclude(
    Q(start_date__lt=arrival) & \
    Q(end_date__gt=arrival) | \
    Q(start_date__lt=departure) & \
    Q(end_date__gt=departure)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This gives me a list of reservations, but I want a list of available houses.

Comment: oh, i've got it. So, just add `.distinct()` to your query (at the end, for example). It will remove duplicates

Comment: Ok lets say for house 120 I have one reservation from 1 May to 5 May, and one reservation from 1 June to 6 June. If I enter arrival date 4 May, and departure date 7 May, the query will return one result. I am on the wrong way now, because when one of the reservations matches, the query should be empty (not available). I am not sure how .distinct() can help here....

Comment: a +1 for the distinct() tip

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that it is not possible to do what I wanted. So I choose a different approach:

Make a list of all rental_units: all_units

Make a list of rental_units from the query below, and remove these list items from all_units:

```
rental_units.objects.filter(group__rental_group = 'Bungalow').filter(Q(Reservations__start_date__gt = arrival)&Q(Reservations__start_date__lt = departure)|Q(Reservations__end_date__gt = arrival)&Q(Reservations__end_date__lt = departure))
```

I enhanced the queryset, so it differs from the topic start.

The queryset returns all Bungalows that have a reservation between the arrival and departure date.